# How to add records with translation into a fixture symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, translation, fixtures

I need some solution for add recors with translation to en and es language into a fixture using translatable plugin from gedmo/doctrine-extensions.

I tested few ways but I can't get the goal

```
        $musicGenre = new MusicalGenre();
        $musicGenre->setName($genre);
        $musicGenre->setEnabled(true);
        $this->addReference(self::MUSIC_GENRE_REFERENCE."-".$key, $musicGenre);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre);

        /*$musicGenre2 = new MusicalGenreTranslation();
        $musicGenre2->setLocale('es_ES');
        $musicGenre2->setObjectClass(MusicalGenre::class);
        $musicGenre2->setField('genre');
        $musicGenre2->setContent($genre);
        $musicGenre2->setForeignKey($key+1);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre2);*/
```

I don't know how I can set or update each record with the other language (es), because default records are inserted with English.

Comment: What's wrong with the given code? In which parts does it depend on translations?

Answer (score 0):

I find an ugly solution, but runs.

```
$musicGenre = new MusicalGenre();
        $musicGenre->setName($genre);
        $musicGenre->setEnabled(true);
        $musicGenre->setCreatedBy('admin');
        $musicGenre->setUpdatedBy('admin');
        $musicGenre->setCreatedAt(new DateTime());
        $musicGenre->setUpdatedAt(new DateTime());
        **$musicGenre->setTranslatableLocale('en');**
        $this->addReference(self::MUSIC_GENRE_REFERENCE."-".$key, $musicGenre);
        $manager->persist($musicGenre);
        $manager->flush();

        $musicGenre2 = new MusicalGenreTranslation();
        $musicGenre2->setLocale('es');
        $musicGenre2->setObjectClass(MusicalGenre::class);
        $musicGenre2->setField('name');
        $musicGenre2->setContent(self::GENRES_ES[$key]);
        $musicGenre2->setForeignKey($musicGenre->getId());
        $manager->persist($musicGenre2);
        $manager->flush();

        $musicGenre3 = new MusicalGenreTranslation();
        $musicGenre3->setLocale('en');
        $musicGenre3->setObjectClass(MusicalGenre::class);
        $musicGenre3->setField('name');
        $musicGenre3->setContent($genre);
        $musicGenre3->setForeignKey($musicGenre->getId());
        $manager->persist($musicGenre3);
        $manager->flush();
```

On the first block I insert the musical genre on the table. For its translations I'm doing a manual insertion on musical genre translations with the locale.